# Trying to delete an instance of a class

Tags: python, class, methods

Here is my code:

```
def ___del____(self):
    return


def delcustomer(self, delname):

    if self.clearance <2:
        return ("Access denied")        
    else:
        del(delname)
```

There is an instance of a class that has a clearance level 2 so he is allowed to delete other instances. say that instance name is Dylan. there is another person being deleted with the name Alex so I was thinking that I could call the method by typing `Dylan.delcustomer(Alex)`. which which would then call `del(Alex)` and delete that instance. But for some reason it just does nothing.

Comment: please add code spacing. it is hard to see what is indented or not

Comment: Python has no way to explicitly delete objects.

Comment: `del identifier` does not delete anything.  It simply unbinds that identifier in the appropriate namespace and decreases the objects reference count by one.  `del something` does not call the `__del__` method of the object.  `__del__` is only called when the objects reference count reaches zero. [See here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)

Comment: Yes I also tried delname.__del__() And that didn't work

Comment: Why do you care whether or not `__del__` gets called --- it explicitly does nothing.  It sounds like your idea of "deleting" an object would be better modeled by removing them from a collection of some sort --- a list or set called `customers`, perhaps.

Comment: It has to be instances of a class. So a list would not work in this scenario

Comment: Why can't you store instances in a list?  At least one of us is terribly confused now.

Comment: Ok so even if I put all the instances in a list then remove I want from the list it is not my main goal. I want the instance to not be recognized any more. That's why I want the __del__ special method. Like if I have an instance Alex with his info then write del (Alex)  in the terminal the special method delete it